# Por qué sólo se actualiza parte del componente cuando uso UseEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hice un proyecto de React, llamando a una api de imágenes de perritos para practicar la funcionalidad de UseEffect.

Quiero que se actualice una etiqueta de párrafo en mi componente Dogs, cuando realizo un cambio en el component principal App. Por eso las conecté por props y armé un hook UseEffect para actualizarlo, pero por algún motivo pareciera no funcionar. Lo raro es que hay parte del componente que sí se actualiza con lo cual el cambio del estado sí se está efectuando. Alguno sabe por qué ocurre esto?

Y una segunda duda. También puse un Loader (un cartel que dice "cargando"). Si bien funciona no estoy 100% satisfecho ya que me gustaría que este desapareciera justito antes de que apareciera la imagen. Cómo debería hacer para que esto ocurriera?

COMPONENTE APP

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Dogs from "./Dogs";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { url: "", raza: "beagle" };
    this.selectRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleChange = () => {
    const nuevaRaza = this.selectRef.current.value;
    this.setState({ raza: nuevaRaza });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>DOGGYS! </h1>
        <select ref={this.selectRef} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value="beagle">beagle</option>
          <option value="hound">hound</option>
          <option value="doberman">doberman</option>
          <option value="eskimo">eskimo</option>
          <option value="labraador">labrador</option>
          <option value="maltese">maltese</option>
        </select>
        <Dogs raza={this.state.raza} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

COMPONENTE DOGS

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Dogs = (props) => {
  const [raza, setRaza] = useState(props.raza);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);


  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await fetch(
        `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${raza}/images/random`
      );
      const response = await request.json();
      setLoading(false);
      setUrl(response.message);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [props.raza]);

  const dogImg = <img alt="" src={url} />;
  let loadMessage;
  if (loading === true) {
    loadMessage = <p>cargando...</p>;
  } else {
    loadMessage = "";
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1> dog photo</h1>
      <p> La raza del perro es: {raza}</p>
      {loadMessage}
      {dogImg}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dogs;
```

Comment: "Lo raro es que hay parte del componente que sí se actualiza" Puedes especificar que parte es la que se actualiza y cual no?

Comment: hola! perdón la demora. La parte que sí se actualiza es la linea que dice const [raza, setRaza] = useState(props.raza); en el componente Dogs. De hecho uso Raza como parte de la url en el fetch.  Y aún así, la constante raza- que en ese caso sí se actualiza en Dogs cuando la modifico en App-  es justamente la que no estoy pudiendo actualizar en la parte de Dogs que dice <p> La raza del perro es: {raza}</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta es muy buena pregunta, lo normal es poder usar las propiedades que recibimos de la propagación del Parent dentro del Leaf components, sin embargo, hay que tomar en cuenta ciertos aspectos.

Dentro del *componente Dog*, si hacemos un console.log a la constante `raza` **después de la asignación del primer Hook useState**, siempre veremos el valor inicial definido en state Parent, que en este caso es "beagle", aunque ya hayamos cambiado la opción del select y además, reasignado este valor a la constante `raza`, con el Hook useState:

```
 const [raza, setRaza] = useState(props.raza);
    const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    //aqui siempre sera beagle, sin importar que ya hayamos cambiado la opción
    //desde el parent y disparado el re-render con setState en el handle
    console.log(raza);
```

Tal vez no te diste cuenta, pero aquí `raza` tampoco cambia, siempre vas por "beagle":

```
//aqui siempre vas por beagle, raza no cambia su valor en cada re-render
const request = await fetch(
        `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${raza}/images/random`
      );
```

Luego, cuando tratamos de usar otras constantes definidas en el **Hook useState** como `loading` o `url`, para pintar vDOM, actualizan sus valores con `setUrl/setLoading` y funcionan, pero la constante `raza` **no**.

Esto es debido a que nunca se esta usando la función `setRaza` del primer Hook, inlcuso React nos avisa de esta situación al correr la App. Otro detalle es que **useState**, *no une* un viejo estado con uno nuevo.

Ahora, el *Leaf Component Dog* usa esta propiedad **raza** desde el Parent (**state as props**), es decir no es una propiedad de instancia del componente *Dog*, como lo son `loading` o `url`, por lo tanto debemos usar la referencia de esa propiedad,  en vez de querer re-asignarla creando otro objeto state. Hacer esto parece un *anti-patrón*, pues **el dueño** del estado `raza` es el Parent component.

Por ejemplo, condicionamos el *Hook* **useEffect** para observar por cambios en `props.raza`, el hook solo se dispára cuando `props.raza` cambie, desde el Parent:

```
useEffect(() => {
      //some code
      
    }, [props.raza]); //condicion de disparo
```

Entonces, lo mas lógico es usar el valor `props.raza` para pintar su **vDOM actualizado**. `props.raza` no es una propiedad de instancia del componente Dog, viene desde el Parent:

```
<p> La raza del perro es: {props.raza}</p>
```

La sugerencia es identificar cuando usamos **state as props** que se propagan, desde Parent Component, a Leaf Components con Hooks y con Class/functional Components por igual. Puesto que el dueño del estado es el Parent, todos los cambios deben venir tambien del mismo, nuestros componentes deben consumir estos cambios de estado desde el Parent, por medio de **props**.

Con respecto al Loader, puedes implementar un `setTimeOut` para tu función `setUrl`, pero debes tener en cuenta la imágen que ya se renderizo.

```
setTimeOut(()=>{
setUrl(response.message);
},1000);
```

El *componenet Dog*, ya con los cambios requeridos, puede quedar configurado de la siguiente forma:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const Dogs = (props) => {
    
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await fetch(
        `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/${props.raza}/images/random`
      );
      const response = await request.json();
      setLoading(false);
  
      setUrl(response.message);
    
    }
    fetchData();
    
  }, [props.raza]);
  
  const dogImg = <img alt="" src={url} />;
  let loadMessage;
  if (loading === true) {
    loadMessage = <p>cargando...</p>;
  } else {
    loadMessage = "";
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1> dog photo</h1>
      <p> La raza del perro es: {props.raza}</p>
      {loadMessage}
      {dogImg}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dogs;
```

Comment: muchas gracias! súper claro, anduvo bárbaro

Comment: Muy bien colega @petrushka_95, saludos!